Python: Shutil.move sometimes causes PermissionError [Winerror 17/32]
I have a script running that at a certain stage has to move a lot of files from an internal drive to a network drive using:
for filename in os.listdir(finished_folder):
    source_file_path = os.path.join(finished_folder, filename)
    shutil.move(source_file_path, destination_file_path)

This goes well 99% of the time. I am transferring many thousands of files per day but very occasionally it gives the following error:
05/18/2024 10:37:02 AM Uncaught exception Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\nlvxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 825, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst) OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different drive: 'C:\\Users\\nlvxxxxx\\Desktop\\file.png' -> '\\\\code1\\storage\\TLdata_Projects\\file.png'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\nlvxxxxx\Desktop\script.py", line 552, in <module>
    shutil.move(source_file_path, destination_file_path)   File "C:\Users\nlvxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 846, in move
    os.unlink(src) PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process does not have access to the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\nlv22087\\Desktop\\file.png'

When I look at the source and file destination after the error, the file exists on both locations. So it has copied it but then can not proceed for some reason due to the above mentioned error.
Did not try anything else to solve it, I can fix it by a try, exception block if there are no other known solutions, this will probably work, but would like to have other thoughts before implementing it

When moving files using the shutil.move module under Windows, you may encounter a PermissionError: [WinError 32] error, which is usually because the target file is being used by another process. Here are some ways to solve this problem:
Method 1: Make sure the file is not in use
Make sure the target file is not in use by other programs or processes. You can check and close possible file usage by following the steps below:
Close applications that may be using the file:
Check if any open applications (such as text editors, image viewers, etc.) are using the file. If so, close these applications.
Check file locks using Explorer:
Open Task Manager and see if any process is using the file.
You can use the Process Explorer tool provided by Sysinternals to find which process has locked the file.
Download Process Explorer, run it, and then press Ctrl+F to search for the file name. If you find the relevant process, you can try to end the process.
Method 2: Use file locking tools
You can write some code to check and unlock the file. Here is an example that uses the psutil module to find and terminate the process using the file:
import psutil
import os
import shutil

def find_and_terminate_process(file_path):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name', 'open_files']):
        for file in proc.info['open_files'] or []:
            if file.path == file_path:
                print(f"Terminating process {proc.info['name']} (PID: {proc.info['pid']}) using the file.")
                proc.terminate()
                proc.wait()
                return

file_path = 'path/to/your/file.txt'
destination_path = 'path/to/destination/'

# 尝试终止占用文件的进程
find_and_terminate_process(file_path)

# 现在尝试移动文件
try:
    shutil.move(file_path, destination_path)
    print("File moved successfully.")
except PermissionError as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")


Perhaps it is a antivirus program or something? Maybe I can build in a retry?
